Airflow dynamicaly mapped tasks don't run in sequence
Hello I have a use case where I need to run a sequence of transformations on a collection of data. 
I grouped the sequence of transformation in a task group in order to dynamically map the tg to the list of data received from a previous task.
Here's a snippet similar to what I'm trying to achieve with the dag so you can have a better idea.
with DAG(
    dag_id="sandbox",
    start_date=datetime(2024, 1, 1, 9),
    schedule_interval=None,
    catchup=False,
    max_active_runs=1,
    default_args={
    }
) as dag:
    @task
    def return_a_list():
        return [i for i in range(20)]
    
    @task_group
    def tg(n):
        @task
        def task1(n):
            print("task1 received " + str(n) + " at " + str(datetime.now()))
            return n
        
        @task
        def task2(n):
            print("task2 received " + str(n) + " at " + str(datetime.now()))

        task2(task1(n))



    nbrs = return_a_list()
    tg.expand(n=nbrs)


The problem is that the first task is executed 20 times (ie: for all the nbrs) before the second task execute for the whole of the nbrs as well, like this (task1)x20 >> (task2)x20.

where in reality i want the tasks to be executed one after another for each nbr coming from the expansion, like this (task1>>task2)x20.
My doubt is around the usage of expansion, is it the correct way to achieve what I described or should I group the tasks in one function and revert to using a for loop instead of trying to do it the "airflowy" way? if it is, what am I doing wrong here?

You can't do that with airflow, dynamic task mapping is about having N run of a task where N is decide at run time.
So if you have a pipeline task_a >> task_b (where each is a dynamic task) airflow will run the N task_a then and only then the M task_b
